# Multiplying event case class depending on the list based on nested IDs

Tags: scala, apache-spark-dataset

I am processing a dataframe and converting into Dataset[Event] using Event case class.How ever there are nested Ids for which i need to multiply the events based on the flattening of nested device:os.

I am able to return the case class Event at the Kafka event level. But not sure how to multiply events .

Kafka incoming Event:

```
{
  "partition": 1,
  "key": "34768_20220203_MFETP501",
  "offset": 1841543,
  "createTime": 1646041475348,
  "topic": "topic_int",
  "publishTime": 1646041475344,
  "errorCode": 0,
  "userActions": {
    "productId": "3MFETP501",
    "createdDate": "2022-02-26T11:19:35.786Z",
    "events": [
      {
        "GUID": "dbb1-f38b-f7f0-44af-90da-80179412f89c",
        "eventDate": "2022-02-26T11:19:35.786Z",
        "familyId": 2010,
        "productTypeId": 1004678,
        "serialID": "890479804",
        "productName": "MFE Total Protection 2021 Family Pack",
        "features": {
          "mapping": [
            {
              "deviceId": 999795,
              "osId": [
                100
              ]
            },
            {
              "deviceId": 987875
              "osId": [
                101
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

The expected output case classes for Event

```
Event("3MFETP501","1004678","2010","3MFETP501:890479804","MFE Total Protection 2021 Family Pack","999795_100", Map("targetId"->"999795_100") )
Event("3MFETP501","1004678","2010","3MFETP501:890479804","MFE Total Protection 2021 Family Pack","987875_100", Map("targetId"->"987875_100") )
```

```
case class Event(
                    productId: String,
                    familyId: String,
                    productTypeId: String,
                    key: String,
                    productName: String,
                    deviceOS:String, 
                    var featureMap: mutable.Map[String, String])




val finalDataset:Dataset[Event] = inputDataFrame.flatMap(
row=> {

        val productId = row.getAs[String]("productId")
        val userActions = row.getAs[Row]("userActions")
        val userEvents:mutable.Seq[Row] = userActions.getAs[mutable.WrappedArray[Row]]("events")

        val processedEvents:mutable.Seq[Row]= userEvents.map(
          event=> 

            val productTypeId = event.getAs[Int]("productTypeId")
            val familyId = event.getAs[String]("familyId")
            val features = activity.getAs[mutable.WrappedArray[Row]]("features")
            val serialId = activity.getAs[String]("serialId")
            val key =  productId+":"+serialId
            val features = mutable.Map[String, String]().withDefaultValue(null)
            

            val device_os_list=List("999795_100","987875_101")
            //Feature Map is for every device_os ( example "targetId"->"999795_100") for 999795_100

      if (familyId == 2010 )
    {
      val a: Option[List[String]] = flatten the deviceId,osId ..
      
      a.get.map(i=>{
          val key: String =  methodToCombinedeviceIdAndosId
          val featureMapping: mutable.Map[String, String] = getfeatureMapForInvidualKey

          Event(productId,productTypeId,familyId,key,productName,device_os,feature) ---> This is returning **List[Event]** 
        })
      }
    else{
    Event(productId,productTypeId,familyId,key,productName,device_os,feature)  --> This is returning **Event**. THIS WORKS

    }
            
        )

}

)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not implement it fully the same but I think it will be possible to understand logic and apply it on your case.

I created json file like *kafka.json* and put there code like this(your event):

```
[{
  "partition": 1,
  "key": "34768_20220203_MFETP501",
  "offset": 1841543,
  "createTime": 1646041475348,
  "topic": "topic_int",
  "publishTime": 1646041475344,
  "errorCode": 0,
  "userActions": {
    "productId": "3MFETP501",
    "createdDate": "2022-02-26T11:19:35.786Z",
    "events": [
      {
        "GUID": "dbb1-f38b-f7f0-44af-90da-80179412f89c",
        "eventDate": "2022-02-26T11:19:35.786Z",
        "familyId": 2010,
        "productTypeId": 1004678,
        "serialID": "890479804",
        "productName": "MFE Total Protection 2021 Family Pack",
        "features": {
          "mapping": [
            {
              "deviceId": 999795,
              "osId": [
                100
              ]
            },
            {
              "deviceId": 987875,
              "osId": [
                101
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}]
```

Please find below first solution that is based on *flatMap* and *for* loop.

```
  case class Event(
      productId: String,
      familyId: String,
      productTypeId: String,
      key: String,
      productName: String,
      deviceOS: String,
      featureMap: Map[String, String])

  import org.apache.spark.sql.{Dataset, Row, SparkSession}

  import scala.collection.mutable

  val spark = SparkSession
      .builder
      .appName("StructuredStreaming")
      .master("local[*]")
      .getOrCreate()

  private val inputDataFrame = spark.read.option("multiline", "true").format("json").load("/absolute_path_to_kafka.json")


  import spark.implicits._

  val finalDataset: Dataset[Event] = inputDataFrame.flatMap(
    row => {

      val userActions = row.getAs[Row]("userActions")
      val productId = userActions.getAs[String]("productId")

      val userEvents = userActions.getAs[mutable.WrappedArray[Row]]("events")
      for (event <- userEvents;
           familyId = event.getAs[Int]("familyId").toString;
           productTypeId = event.getAs[Int]("productTypeId").toString;
           serialId = event.getAs[String]("serialID");
           productName = event.getAs[String]("productName");
           key = s"$productId:$serialId";
           features = event.getAs[Row]("features");
           mappings = features.getAs[mutable.WrappedArray[Row]]("mapping");
           mappingRow <- mappings;
           deviceId = mappingRow.getAs[Long]("deviceId");
           osIds = mappingRow.getAs[mutable.WrappedArray[Long]]("osId");
           osId <- osIds;
           deviseOs = deviceId + "_" + osId
           ) yield Event(productId, familyId, productTypeId, key, productName, deviseOs, Map("target" -> (deviseOs)))
    }

  )

  finalDataset.foreach(e => println(e))

//  Event(3MFETP501,2010,1004678,3MFETP501:890479804,MFE Total Protection 2021 Family Pack,999795_100,Map(target -> 999795_100))
//  Event(3MFETP501,2010,1004678,3MFETP501:890479804,MFE Total Protection 2021 Family Pack,987875_101,Map(target -> 987875_101))
```

Also, you can solve this task using *select*, *withColumn*, *[explode](https://sparkbyexamples.com/spark/explode-spark-array-and-map-dataframe-column/)*, *[concat](https://sparkbyexamples.com/spark/spark-concatenate-dataframe-columns/)* functions.

```
  case class Event(
      productId: String,
      familyId: String,
      productTypeId: String,
      key: String,
      productName: String,
      deviceOS: String,
      featureMap: Map[String, String])

  import org.apache.spark.sql.{Dataset, SparkSession}
  import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.{col, explode, concat, lit, map}

  val spark = SparkSession
      .builder
      .appName("StructuredStreaming")
      .master("local[*]")
      .getOrCreate()

  private val inputDataFrame = spark.read.option("multiline", "true").format("json").load("/absolute_path_to_kafka.json")

  val transformedDataFrame = inputDataFrame
      .select(col("userActions.productId").as("productId"),
        explode(col("userActions.events")).as("event"))
      .select(col("productId"),
        col("event.familyId").as("familyId"),
        col("event.productTypeId").as("productTypeId"),
        col("event.serialID").as("serialID"),
        col("event.productName").as("productName"),
        explode(col("event.features.mapping")).as("features")
      )
      .select(
        col("productId"),
        col("familyId"),
        col("productTypeId"),
        col("serialID"),
        col("productName"),
        col("features.deviceId").as("deviceId"),
        explode(col("features.osId")).as("osId")
      )
      .withColumn("key", concat(col("productId"), lit(":"), col("serialID")))
      .withColumn("deviceOS", concat(col("deviceId"), lit("_"), col("osId")))
      .withColumn("featureMap", map(lit("target"), col("deviceOS")))

  import spark.implicits._

  private val result: Dataset[Event] = transformedDataFrame.as[Event]
  result.foreach(e => println(e))

//  Event(3MFETP501,2010,1004678,3MFETP501:890479804,MFE Total Protection 2021 Family Pack,999795_100,Map(target -> 999795_100))
//  Event(3MFETP501,2010,1004678,3MFETP501:890479804,MFE Total Protection 2021 Family Pack,987875_101,Map(target -> 987875_101))
```

Add option to customize response based on the value one of the field. I replace here *for* comprehension to *map/flatmap*, so you can return as response one or several events based on the type. Also, I customized json a little bit to show more examples in the result.

New json:

```
[{
  "partition": 1,
  "key": "34768_20220203_MFETP501",
  "offset": 1841543,
  "createTime": 1646041475348,
  "topic": "topic_int",
  "publishTime": 1646041475344,
  "errorCode": 0,
  "userActions": {
    "productId": "3MFETP501",
    "createdDate": "2022-02-26T11:19:35.786Z",
    "events": [
      {
        "GUID": "dbb1-f38b-f7f0-44af-90da-80179412f89c",
        "eventDate": "2022-02-26T11:19:35.786Z",
        "familyId": 2010,
        "productTypeId": 1004678,
        "serialID": "890479804",
        "productName": "MFE Total Protection 2021 Family Pack",
        "features": {
          "mapping": [
            {
              "deviceId": 999795,
              "osId": [
                100,
                110
              ]
            },
            {
              "deviceId": 987875,
              "osId": [
                101
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      {
        "GUID": "1111-2222-f7f0-44af-90da-80179412f89c",
        "eventDate": "2022-03-26T11:19:35.786Z",
        "familyId": 2011,
        "productTypeId": 1004679,
        "serialID": "890479805",
        "productName": "Product name",
        "features": {
          "mapping": [
            {
              "deviceId": 999796,
              "osId": [
                103
              ]
            },
            {
              "deviceId": 987877,
              "osId": [
                104
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}]
```

Please find code below:

```
  case class Event(
      productId: String,
      familyId: String,
      productTypeId: String,
      key: String,
      productName: String,
      deviceOS: String,
      featureMap: Map[String, String])

  import org.apache.spark.sql.{Dataset, SparkSession}

  val spark = SparkSession
      .builder
      .appName("StructuredStreaming")
      .master("local[*]")
      .getOrCreate()

  private val inputDataFrame = spark.read.option("multiline", "true").format("json").load("/absolute_path_to_kafka.json")

  import spark.implicits._

  val finalDataset: Dataset[Event] = inputDataFrame.flatMap(
    row => {

      val userActions = row.getAs[Row]("userActions")
      val productId = userActions.getAs[String]("productId")

      val userEvents = userActions.getAs[mutable.WrappedArray[Row]]("events")
      for (event <- userEvents;
           productTypeId = event.getAs[Int]("productTypeId").toString;
           serialId = event.getAs[String]("serialID");
           productName = event.getAs[String]("productName");
           key = s"$productId:$serialId";
           familyId = event.getAs[Int]("familyId").toString;
           features = event.getAs[Row]("features");
           mappings = features.getAs[mutable.WrappedArray[Row]]("mapping");
           mappingRow <- mappings;
           deviceId = mappingRow.getAs[Long]("deviceId");
           osIds = mappingRow.getAs[mutable.WrappedArray[Long]]("osId");
           osId <- osIds;
           deviseOs = deviceId + "_" + osId
           ) yield Event(productId, familyId, productTypeId, key, productName, deviseOs, Map("target" -> deviseOs))

      userEvents.flatMap(event => {
        val productTypeId = event.getAs[Int]("productTypeId").toString
        val serialId = event.getAs[String]("serialID")
        val productName = event.getAs[String]("productName")
        val key = s"$productId:$serialId"
        val familyId = event.getAs[Long]("familyId")

        if(familyId == 2010) {
          val features = event.getAs[Row]("features")
          val mappings = features.getAs[mutable.WrappedArray[Row]]("mapping")
          mappings.flatMap(mappingRow => {
            val deviceId = mappingRow.getAs[Long]("deviceId")
            val osIds = mappingRow.getAs[mutable.WrappedArray[Long]]("osId")
            osIds.map(osId => {
              val devise_os = deviceId + "_" + osId
              Event(productId, familyId.toString, productTypeId, key, productName, devise_os, Map("target" -> devise_os))
            })
          })
        } else {
          Seq(Event(productId, familyId.toString, productTypeId, key, productName, "default_defice_os", Map("target" -> "default_defice_os")))
        }
      })

    }
  )

  finalDataset.foreach(e => println(e))

//  Event(3MFETP501,2010,1004678,3MFETP501:890479804,MFE Total Protection 2021 Family Pack,999795_100,Map(target -> 999795_100))
//  Event(3MFETP501,2010,1004678,3MFETP501:890479804,MFE Total Protection 2021 Family Pack,999795_110,Map(target -> 999795_110))
//  Event(3MFETP501,2010,1004678,3MFETP501:890479804,MFE Total Protection 2021 Family Pack,987875_101,Map(target -> 987875_101))
//  Event(3MFETP501,2011,1004679,3MFETP501:890479805,Product name,default_defice_os,Map(target -> default_defice_os))
```

Comment: Event row is at one level . How ever depending on the product type==x, I have to parse the features. and under features there can be multiple sets of deviceId:OsID. You are processing them at same level. How will it work ? For all other product types, events at same level should be returned

Comment: In my case you extract values from array and duplicate all other fields. For example, you have such row in dataframe `{name: "User", features: [1, 2]}` it will be converted to two records like this `{name: "User", feature: 1}, {name: "User", feature: 2}`. It will work the same for all cases where I work with array.
In any case you can customize code, for instance add if/else in for statement, where set needed values.
Can you please provide full requirements? Because it is hard to solve one issue, after you are adding new requirements

Comment: Also, could you provide raw data and expected results?

Comment: I added third solution, that I believe do what you want. It return one or several events based on the value of column *familyId*. @CoolGoose please look and say if it what you want.

Comment: Did last solution help you?

Comment: Still working on it . Not exactly that solution. but i got the idea.

Answer (score 0):

As this is under a Row of DataFrame, returning Event case class , converts into DataSet.Issue here is for one condition ,i am getting **List[Event]** and rest type , i am getting only **Event** class

FYI :This is not an answer. But my further attempt to solve.

```
if (familyId == 2010 )
    {
      val a: Option[List[String]] = flatten the deviceId,osId ..
      
      a.get.map(i=>{
          val key: String =  methodToCombinedeviceIdAndosId
          val featureMapping: mutable.Map[String, String] = getfeatureMapForInvidualKey

          Event(productId,productTypeId,familyId,key,productName,device_os,feature) ---> This is returning List[Event]
        })
      }
    else{
    Event(productId,productTypeId,familyId,key,productName,device_os,feature)  --> This is returning Event

    }
```

Comment: Add please it to the initial post, it will confuse other users who will look at the solution.